# Regex with Google CloudVision API

Tags: regex, google-cloud-vision

I'm new in regex and I'm trying to only display this on a site using regex:

```
"joyLikelihood": "VERY_LIKELY",
"sorrowLikelihood": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
"angerLikelihood": "VERY_UNLIKELY",
"surpriseLikelihood": "VERY_UNLIKELY"
```

How do you think should I go about it? since the `"very_likely"` or `"VERY_UNLIKELY"` results depending on the image.

Comment: as far as i know the returned results are the same as you mentioned. what do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to display only that four results not the other things like the eye locations and the likes

Comment: what i would do is parsing the returned JSON and use the keys i want. What platform does your program run?

Comment: I've tried parsing but I'm kinda having trouble displaying it on the html file i created.

Comment: would you mind if we move the discussion to chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110794/regex-with-google-cloudvision-api

Comment: sorry. seems that I cant. I need 20 reputation. and i just created this account minutes ago.

Comment: If you want to get a part of your text; you can use a regex like `/"[^"]+"\s*:\s*"very_(un)?likely",?/igm` - HTH ;).